# GTM Google Tag: not found

Tags: analytics, tag-manager, gtm

I have a few months working over the implementation of Google Tag Manager into a site created by using Salesforce.
I followed all the instructions for the installation of it, and everything seemed to work fine (events, conversions, preview mode, etc.). Until we realized the traffic at the site was not the expected, so development team suggested me to change the normal script tag used in the GTM implementation for a x-oasis-script. This solve the traffic issue, now we are getting the traffic as planned; but events stopped triggering also affecting our conversions.

With this  when we try to track our Google Tag by using the "Preview Mode" we get the error "**google tag: not found**" as if not installed (Something that didn't happen when we tried with the normal script tag).

These are both scripts we are using:

1. The one with x-oasis-script tag, the one that looks like the site is not detecting, as if its not installed.

   ```
   <x-oasis-script hidden="true">(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
   new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
   j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
   'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
   })(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-XXXXXXX');</x-oasis-script>
   ```
2. The one that seems to work fine, but affect our traffic site.

   ```
   <script hidden="true">(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
   new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
   j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
   'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
    })(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-XXXXXXX');</script>
   ```

I supposed the correct implementation is the one using the x-oasis-script but what I want to know is why our site is not dettecting it. Or why we are losing traffic by using the normal script tag.

I would appreciate your support over this.